Windows Defender detecting and submitting samples even when I've turned off Automatic Sample Submission
Background:
So, I was kind of playing around with this virus on my computer to see how well Windows Defender could detect it. To make sure it would not get signatured by Microsoft, I turned off the Automatic Sample Submission feature. But Windows Defender still managed to block it, using some behavioral analysis.
Problem:
After I deleted the virus, I got a notification at 2:00 am and it was the virus connecting to my server, even though I hadn't shared it or uploaded it to places like VirusTotal. Upon digging into it, turns out the virus was operating in some sandbox thing, trying to access external resources like api.ipify.com, but failing because of the sandbox restrictions. However, it still found a way to connect to my server and send out some info.
Concern:
The virus was only on my PC, and I had disabled sample submission.
Question:
Why is Windows Defender still detecting and submitting samples when I've clearly turned off Automatic Sample Submission? Is this normal, or is there something else going on here? Can anyone shed some light on this?

Probably the Automatic Sample Submission turned on by itself. I've seen that sometimes some of the options like Real Time Protection turns on by itself after a restart.
